# RSS парсер

Tags: android, java

Привет всем. Возник вопрос. Есть rss парсер. Он работает хорошо, но только с rss лентами, которые используют UTF-8, а мне нужно, чтобы бы он работал с windows-1251. 
Вот часть кода:

```
SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Привет. Попробуй для InputSource использовать "setEncoding", т.е. в вашем случае:

```
myInputSource.setEncoding("windows-1251");
```